# Map custom DTO to breeze entities

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, single-page-application

Is it possible to map  Flatened object to breeze entities? I have a DTO which is built up from multiple datasets but I am having trouble manipulating the data on the client. I would like the custom DTO to be part of the breeze metedata. below is a sample of the DTO.

```
Public class TimeKeepingItem
{
    public int ClientId{ get; set; }
    public string ClientName{ get; set; }
    public string ClientSurname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    {
        get { return Date.DayOfWeek.ToString(); }
    }
}

Public class TimeKeepingContainer
{
      public List<TimeKeepingItems> TimekeepingItems {get;set;}

      //other properties

}
```

I would like to convert both the above classes to breeze entities on the client.

Comment: Yep, you can easily do that, as long as you have an entity to map it back to with the correct properties.  See the docs http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/add-new-entity

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if you understand what I am trying to do. Breeze generates entities from from the data context's metadata. The DTO I am using is not part of the database context so it is not on the metadata. So i would like to manually add the DTO on the breeze metadata for easier data manipulation on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

PW Kad's comment is correct, you can also take a look at the Edmunds and NoDb samples in the Breeze zip.

Comment: Thank you, your comment gave me direction. Here is the url to the NoDB sample http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb